# Security violation - Fortify, MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fortify

I am using HP Fortify to address the security issues in my application.
I have a piece of code as below for which Fortify throws an error.

The Fortify result says:

> The method DownloadAttachment() in ***fileName***.cs includes unvalidated
>   data in an HTTP response header on line ***lineNo***. This enables attacks
>   such as cache-poisoning, cross-site scripting, cross-user defacement,
>   page hijacking, cookie manipulation or open redirect.

Code -

```
    public ActionResult DownloadAttachment(string fullFilePath)
    {
        var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fullFilePath);
        return File(bytes, MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fullFilePath), Path.GetFileName(fullFilePath));
    }
```

What is the threat here and how to address this? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HP is right this is a problem but not in the way they are saying -- the threat here is that you've got an action method that will load any file the web server can read and let a visitor download it. This could easily lead to other attacks depending on what someone downloaded and your networking setup.

What you need to do is handle attachments a bit more carefully and a bit less generically -- this could be just taking the file name as a parameter and looking in a given folder for example.

Comment: I wouldn't rule out a response header poisoning vulnerability. But you are correct, that the design of this method is a greater problem than the header poisoning.